# How to add `Tip` though the Square API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, square

I am using the Square's OrderAPI + TransactionAPI to handle my eCommerce checkout and everything is working great so far. However, I've just received a requirement from my client to add the `tip` section to the checkout, where customers will inform how much tip they will give. Is it something doable using the current Square's Api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to add a tip via Square's APIs.